# How to count each true element within cases in an array of objects in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to get the number of items that meet the true condition in the status field for every cases.
for example:
[Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Dgx.png)

Output:

```
{“user_id”: “4-389-739”,“case1”:0,“case2”:3,“case3”:1,“case4”:1 }
```

Comment: Please don't use images for code/data/errors/etc.  Just include them in a code block.

Answer (score 1):

The user id part is not sure from where you are getting in document i believe you can figure it out but for help you out with counting the cases this might help you

```
      {
    $group: {
     
      "case1": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{ $in: [true, "$case1.status"] }, 1, 0]
        }
      },
"case2": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{ $in: [true, "$case2.status"] }, 1, 0]
        }
      }
    }
  }

you can generalize here and add as many conditioin as possible
```

Comment: user_id is included. you can find it at the end of the Document